# ReactNative: Как выключить экран при обнаружении "близости" (proximity)?

Tags: react-native, экран, display, hide

react-native-keep-awake & expo-keep-awake для меня не работают.

Использую react-native-proximity для обнаружения "близости".

Мне нужно отключать дисплей на время с помощью одного компонента.

Спасибо. :)

Comment: Пожалуйста переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, иначе он будет закрыт за несоответствия правилам публикации вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо.) Думал пишу на английской части.